# How to convert array into int in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

My field in table is an array and I want to convert it to an int.

```
$totalreward = DB::table('bid_packs')
    ->select('bid_pack_reward_points')->first();
$solve = $totalreward * $qty;

print_r ($solve);
```

It always prompt this error

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Comment: What are the fields in your tables?

Comment: its too many but i want to select the bid_pack_reward_points for computing the qty

Answer (score 1):

`DB::table('bid_packs')->select('bid_pack_reward_points')->first();` returns an object that has properties with the names of the fields you selected.

In this case:

```
$totalreward = DB::table('bid_packs')->select('bid_pack_reward_points')->first();
$solve = $totalreward->bid_pack_reward_points * $qty;
print_r ($solve);
```

Or, since you're trying to get one value from the first row, you can use `pluck()` to get straight to the value:

```
$totalreward = DB::table('bid_packs')->pluck('bid_pack_reward_points');
$solve = $totalreward * $qty;
print_r ($solve);
```

Comment: @KouyaMarino No problem. I notice you're a new user, so don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem. This helps maintain the integrity of the site.

Comment: sorry im just newbie in stackoverflow :)

Comment: @KouyaMarino We all were at some point. :) But, that's the reason for the comment, just to help others help contribute to the community. You get the hang of it after a while.

Comment: but theres some problem . :(
i post the problem below i hope you can help me :/ thanks